# How to display oidc App in google workspace

Tags: openid-connect, saml, google-sso, custom-application

hi I created a "custom SAML app" in "admin.google.com" and that SAML app is displayed in "workspace.google.com" I created an OIDC client in "console.cloud.google.com", now I want to create a bridge between all these three so that I can create "custom OIDC app" that can be displayed in "workspace.google.com". How can I do it please provide the steps?